# How to get a hyperlink on a web page to open a file in a text editor (Sublime Text)

Tags: sublimetext

I'm working on a large static website (Jekyll) and would like to be able to click on a link on a page in browser (Chrome) which will open it's corresponding source file on the local machine (Sublime). I can get the absolute link of the file.

From the console (Ubuntu) I can do:

```
subl path/to/file.txt
```

to open a file, so perhaps an extension that allows command execution on trusted domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu**
There is a [solution for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527166/how-to-set-subl-protocol-handler-with-unity)

**Windows Method**

You first have to install a Protocol Handler in the Windows registry.
(Reference:
[Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome))

This will get Chrome to run a command when a `subl:path/to/file` link is clicked. 
But you can't simply run `sublime_text.exe subl:path/to/file`, because Sublime doesn't understand the `subl:path/to/file` parameter. You first have to extract the filename with a script and then call Sublime with a single file parameter.

**Solution 1**

[This](https://github.com/ljubadr/sublime-protocol-win) is a Solution for Windows, that opens links with the format

```
subl://open?url=file://<path_to_file>&line=4
```

It first registers a Script as a Protocol Handler, which in turn calls Sublime

**Solution 2**

I edited Solution 1 to open links in the format

```
subl://path/to/file:line
```

Just follow Solution 1, but change `open_file.vbs` to:

```
' path to sublime_text.exe
Dim sublime_path
' CHANGE THIS:
sublime_path = "C:\Programme\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" 

Dim text, filename
' get first command line argument
text = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

filename  = Split(text, ":/")(1)

Dim run_command
run_command = """"&sublime_path&""" """&filename&""""

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(run_command)
Set objShell = Nothing
```

(You have to change the path to your sublime_text.exe)

**Mac**
https://github.com/corysimmons/subl-handler

Comment: For MacOS: I actually found this repo [inopinatus/sublime_url](https://github.com/inopinatus/sublime_url) to be more recently maintained than corysimmons/subl-handler

Answer (score 0):

There's a Chrome extension, that let's you open a link with an external application: [Open with external application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp)

Comment: Sadly an old plugin, architecture no longer supported: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/FrP5rcV.png)

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but you can try this: subl://path/to/file.txt

Comment: did you suggest this because you had reason to believe that it actually works?  I have never heard of using subl:// in place of http:// and it didn't work when i tried it.  If suggesting "you can try this" it would be good to provide link to a resource which explains why your suggestion should work (assuming you don't explain it yourself)

Comment: I did find this in the xdebug documentation at : https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings  xdebug.file_link_format. So maybe you don't need to be so quick on downvotes. My mistake for not providing more info....

Comment: I was not that quick to downvote, I actually tested your suggestion first and found that it did not work.  But your reply has further confused me, as it is linking to documentation for an "XDEBUG EXTENSION FOR PHP", and the relevance of this to either hyperlink schemas, browser behaviour, or Sublime Text is still unclear.  It's also still unclear whether your solution is something that worked for you (can you follow a subl:// hyperlink on your machine and have it open in Subilme Text directly?) or was your suggestion just something that you found in the doc and suggested blindly?